# ¿Cómo recorrer un array con el bucle for en jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Recorro una lista para imprimir en un PDF utilizando jsPDF:

```
for (i = 0; i <= SRUreport.lista_wps().length; i++) {
    valor_imprimir = (i+'   : '+Ejemplolista[i])[0].trim());
    doc.text(20,100,valor_imprimir);
    alert(valor_imprimir);
}
```

el `alert` funciona correctamente, y me va arrojando los valores de `Ejemplolista` en ventanas emergentes.

Sin embargo, si utilizo la misma variable (`valor_imprimir`) para incluirlo en un PDF utilizando jsPFD me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

¿Por qué no reconoce el valor `[0]` que pertenece al primer string del array `Ejemplolista`?

Comment: Si hay un elemento en la lista con undefined, vas a tener ese resultado. ¿Puedes poner una lista de ejemplo que genere esta salida?, ademas el ultimo [0] ¿para que esta?, ¿quieres obtener el primer caracter de la cadena resultante ?, si la cadena da undefined (por que un elemento de la lista es undefined), es logico que recibas el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comenta rnd si hay un elemento en la lista que es `undefined`, vas a tener el error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '< >' of undefined.

Aunque comentas que puedes imprimir correctamente los valores que tiene `Ejemplolista`, el problema en este caso me parece es debido a que no necesitas el `[0]` en esta linea de código:

```
valor_imprimir = (i+'   : '+Ejemplolista[i])[0].trim());
```

trata únicamente con (también tienes un paréntesis no necesario):

```
  valor_imprimir = (i+'   : '+Ejemplolista[i]).trim();
```

Otro detalle importante que podría causar un bug (indexoutofbounds) es que la cantidad de elementos en `SRUreport.lista_wps().length;` puede ser mayor o menor a los elementos dentro de: `Ejemplolista`

Comment: No entiendo porque si lo meto en un alert me muestra los valores pero no escribe en el documento por error en [0]

Comment: he agregado más información a mi respuesta. Simplemente si haces esto:  <code> valor_imprimir = (i+'   : '+Ejemplolista[i])[0].trim());
 alert(valor_imprimir); </code>, no mostraría el alert, el [0] indica el primer valor del array dentro de:  (i+'   : '+Ejemplolista[i]) lo cual es imposible porque no es un arreglo.

Comment: Si deseas agrega tu ejemplo cuando si muestras los datos en ventanas emergentes y cuando haces el cambio y marca error.